# Динамическое создание блоков

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь по расширению возможности скрипта по добавлению *HTML* тега в *Dom*.

К сожалению, из-за отсутствия соответствующих знаний и аналога в сети, не знаю, как расширить данный скрипт для поддержки добавления не только в одиночном варианте, но и при выборе значения в `select`.

```js
var num = 1;
var $namb = 3;
function addQuestion() {
  if ($namb <= 25) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<input name='voice_var_" + $namb + "'class='form-control' placeholder='Вариант ответа' type='text'><br>";
    //newdiv.appendTo('div#quest');
    document.getElementById("parentId").appendChild(newdiv);
    $namb++;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

<div id="parentId">
</div>
<a class="btn btn-info btm-sm" href="#" role="button" onclick="addQuestion()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Добавить вариант ответа
</a>
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="0">Установить кол-во</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Юзеры, у вас фетиш проснулся к множеству мелких правок, вместо одной, но нормальной?

Comment: В чём собственно вопрос? При выборе в селекте что должно произойти?

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления нескольких элементов можно использовать цикл:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn.btm-sm'),
    select = document.querySelector('.form-control'),
    list = document.querySelector('#parentId');

var $namb = 3;

button.onclick = function(e) {
  // Отключаем стандарные действия по нажатию
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Получаем количество элементов
  var input_length = parseFloat(select.value);
  
  // Создаём цикл
  for(var i = 0; i < input_length; i++){
    if ($namb <= 25) {
      // Добавляем элементы
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.innerHTML = "<input name='voice_var_" + $namb + "'class='form-control' placeholder='Вариант ответа' type='text'><br>";
      document.getElementById("parentId").appendChild(newDiv);
      $namb++;
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="parentId">
</div>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-info btm-sm" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Добавить вариант ответа
  </a>
</p>

<p>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Установить кол-во</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num = 0,
  cntVars = document.getElementById('count_variants'),
  output = document.getElementById('parentId');
document.getElementById('add_variant').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tmp = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    newDiv;
  for (var i = 0; i < cntVars.value; i++) {
    if (num++ < 25) {
      newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.innerHTML = '<input name="voice_var_' + num + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Вариант ответа" type="text" >';
      tmp.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
  }
  output.appendChild(tmp);
  cntVars.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<div id="parentId">
</div>
<a class="btn btn-info btm-sm" href="#" role="button" id="add_variant">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Добавить вариант ответа
</a>
<select class="form-control" id="count_variants">
    <option value="1">Установить кол-во</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```